# ScrollView is not working inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have one fragment called FeedBackFragment And its a Page of ViewPager  and it has `scrollview`. But the scroll is not working.

I have 2 xml files:

*parent.xml*

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

I have scrollview inside *feedback.xml* and it's **not** scrolling.

*feedback.xml*


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.promediadesigns.tecosnation.CustomScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/username"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_et"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="Enter Full Name..."
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textColorHint="#fff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_et"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="Enter Email..."
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textColorHint="#fff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/msg"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/greyround_et"
                        android:hint="Type your message here..."
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/send"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/send_icon" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </com.promediadesigns.tecosnation.CustomScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me out about the scrolling?

Comment: Next time try to ask the question properly, not all with caps, bolds and etc xD

Comment: com.promediadesigns.tecosnation.CustomScrollView  what is this exactly? if you change this to a normal scrollview it works?

Comment: @M.K sure......

Comment: @JoachimHaglund  it isn't working if i change to normal ScrollView

Comment: Is the content taller than the scrollview? Is it even supposed to scroll?

Comment: @JonasBorggren  no content ain't taller but .. there is e edittext and when it is focused and soft keyboard opened now i m seeing edittext half so now scrollview is rquired to see whole edittext and its below contents

Comment: @JonasBorggren any solution?

Comment: set viewpager height to match_parent

Comment: @Athira didn't work

Comment: does your any root view contain CoordinatorLayout ?if so  kindly convert it to normal then convert your feedback layout's scrollview to nested view..

Answer (score 0):

Change your feedbak.xml to

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter Full Name..."
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter Email..."
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/msg"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:hint="Type your message here..."
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: still not scrolling

Comment: What is not scrolling? pager or scrollview?

Comment: scrollview is not scrolling

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments it seem the problem is not actually with the scroll but rather with the softkeyboard covering the editfield, as the content of the scrollview is not actually bigger than the scrollview itself, so there is nothing to scroll.

you need to set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

on your activity to get expected behaviour.

> "adjustResize"    The activity's main window is always resized to make
>   room for the soft keyboard on screen.
>
> "adjustPan"   The activity's main window is not resized to make room for
>   the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are
>   automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by
>   the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is
>   generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to
>   close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of
>   the window.